# Example of a group with elements $a, b$ such that $\mbox{ord}(a) = \mbox{ord}(b) = \mbox{ord}(ab) = 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Give an example of a group $G$ (abelian or not) and two elements $a,b\in G$ such that $\mbox{ord}(a) = \mbox{ord}(b) = \mbox{ord}(ab) = 2$.

I thought about Klein four-group firstly. Does it work? I will be gratefull if you could give any other example.

Comment: Yes, that will work for an abelian one. For a non-abelian one, see if you can find such elements in the dihedral group of order $8$.

Comment: $\text{ord}(a) = \text{ord}(b) = 2$ means that $a^2 = b^2 = e$. Note then, that in an abelian group, $(ab)^2 = abab = aabb = a^2b^2 = e$ so $\text{ord}(ab)$ is at most $2$. Note also that if $ab = e$ and $aa = e$ then $b = a$, thus $\text{ord}(ab) = 2$ as long as $a \neq b$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit more detail showing that it is actually hard to pick wrong when trying to find a suitable group (though it will use some more advanced theory than is expected in an exercise like this. Consider this a bit of a preview of what might be to come).

If $a$, $b$ and $ab$ are as required, then $a$ and $b$ commute, so we can restrict out attention to a $2$-Sylow subgroup. Conversely, if $a$ and $b$ are distinct commuting elements of order $2$, then they clearly work.

This means that we are interested in which $2$-groups have such elements. But it turns out that the only ones that do not are the cyclic groups and the generalized quaternion groups.

The reason is that a $2$-group clearly has a central element of order $2$, so if it does not have elements like the ones we want, this element of order $2$ must be the only such element. If the group is abelian, it is clear that this can only happen if it is cyclic. If it is not abelian, it is a general result that the only non-abelian $2$-groups with a unique element of order $2$ are the generalized quaternion groups. This is not a trivial result, though the proof is not long. It can be found in for example Berkovich's Groups of Prime Power Order vol 1 (it is Proposition 1.3).

Answer (score 1):

According to the question, it means that there exist two elements $a$ and $b$ which commute, but, in general it does not mean the group is Abelian.

The property clearly holds true in a Klein group.

As Tobias pointed out, consider two elements of the diahedral group of order 8: 1) $a$ = vertical flip and 2) $b$ = horizontal flip. Then, $ab$ = rotation by $\pi$. Clearly, $a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^2 = e$

Answer (score 1):

If $\mbox{ord}(a) = \mbox{ord}(b) = \mbox{ord}(ab) = 2$ then $a$ and $b$ generate in $G$ a Klein four-subgroup $K$ and conversely. So for example, for any group $H$ the direct product $K\times H$ is what you want.

Comment: $\otimes$ is usually not used for direct product of groups. Also, which such direct products will work, not all groups with this property will be of that form (I realize you did not claim this, but it might be read that way).

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Of course, thank you. At first I wrote direct sum (\oplus) and then corrected for product (with a typo).

Answer (score 0):

For an abelian group, take the direct sum $G=\oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
Here all elements, except for the identity, have order $2$. In particular, for any $a,b,ab$ different from the identity we have $ord(a)=ord(b)=ord(ab)=2$.
The group is finite, if $I$ is a finite index set. If $I$ has cardinality $2$, it is the Klein four group.

As for non-abelian groups, we can look for examples, which have $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^k$ as Sylow $2$-subgroup. For example, there is a non-abelian group of order $56$ having a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup and whose Sylow $2$-subgroup is $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$. Then take $a,b,ab$ from this Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try using GAP for this question and see what will be achieved.

```
> V:=FreeGroup("a","b");;
> a:=V.1;;   b:=V.2;;
> V4:=V/[a^2,b^2,(a*b)^2];;
> Size(V4);
[ 4 
> Elements(V4);
[ <identity ...>, a, b, a*b ]
> StructureDescription(V4);
[ "C2 x C2"
```

Comment: ;-) Hello, dear friend!